# Vuejs Router and Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, security, vuex, vue-router

I have recently decided to learn Vuejs but I couldn't figure it out if there's a way to load collections once instead of on every component.

This is what I am doing on every component before  `export default`

The main file is where I first loaded the firebase, because of the authentication.

```
import firebase from '../main';
import fb from 'firebase'

let db= ''

if(firebase){
  db = firebase.firestore();
}
else{
  
  var config = {
    apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_APIKEY,
    authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_PROJECTID,
    storageBucket:process.env.VUE_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
    appId: process.env.VUE_APP_APPID,
    measurementId: process.env.VUE_APP_MEASUREMENTID
  };

   let aux_fb =  !fb.apps.length ?  fb.initializeApp(config) : fb.app();
   db = aux_fb.firestore() 
  
}
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router';
import fb from "firebase" ;

var config = {
    apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_APIKEY,
    authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_PROJECTID,
    storageBucket:process.env.VUE_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
    appId: process.env.VUE_APP_APPID,
    measurementId: process.env.VUE_APP_MEASUREMENTID
}

const firebase =  !fb.apps.length ?  fb.initializeApp(config) : fb.app();

export default firebase;

Vue.config.productionTip = false

let app = '';
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
    if (!app) {
      app = new Vue({
        router,
        render: h => h(App)
      }).$mount('#app');
    }
});
```

Also, is it safe to use a .env ?

Comment: If you have global state such as collections the app will use in various components, that's when it's useful to use a central store, i.e. Vuex, where you load data once

Comment: Thank you, your answer was really helpful